# SQL MIN() function not working with bigint values

Tags: sql, aggregate, min

I'm trying to get min value from a series of values but seems min() not correctly working for bigint values.

Ex. 442227741 / 4278215881

If I tried with these 2 values function return min value for 4278215881 . seems it's omitting the last digit of the bigint value & compare. Then it comes 442227741 & 427821588 returning min value as 4278215881.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Of course MIN() is expected to work on bigint...)

Comment: Is that column **really** a `bigint` or did you mess up your data model and store numbers in a `varchar` column?

Comment: Actually this is just like a temp table & store values in varchar column. I have resolved my problem. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are storing the values as strings, but you want a numeric minimum.  One method is to convert to a decimal:

```
select min(cast(col as decimal(20, 0)))
```